# I am getting python error TypeError: String indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Below is the dictionary that I get from a JSON response

```
{u'definitions': [{u'text': u'One venerated for experience, judgment, and wisdom.', u'attribution': u'from The American Heritage\xae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition'}, {u'text': u'Having or exhibiting wisdom and calm judgment.', u'attribution': u'from The American Heritage\xae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition'}, {u'text': u'Proceeding from or marked by wisdom and calm judgment:  sage advice. ', u'attribution': u'from The American Heritage\xae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition'}, {u'text': u'Archaic   Serious; solemn.', u'attribution': u'from The American Heritage\xae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition'}, {u'text': u'Any of various plants of the genus Salvia, especially S. officinalis, having aromatic grayish-green, opposite leaves. Also called ramona.', u'attribution': u'from The American Heritage\xae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition'}, {u'text': u'The leaves of this plant used as a seasoning.', u'attribution': u'from The American Heritage\xae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition'}, {u'text': u'Any of various similar or related plants in the mint family.', u'attribution': u'from The American Heritage\xae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition'}, {u'text': u'Sagebrush.', u'attribution': u'from The American Heritage\xae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition'}]}
```

I am trying to access the first two 'text' by using this code statement:

```
text1 = [body["definitions"][0]["text"],
         body["definitions"][1]["text"]]
```

I get the strings that I need.

But the actual problem is that when I run the same code on my raspberry Pi 2, I get the following error

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On your raspberry PI, you are asking for user input, and ALL user input is a string.  Try this: `data = [10, 20]`, then `print(data["0"])`

Comment: It works fine as shown, assigning that dictionary to `body`. Are you sure you actually created a dictionary, as opposed to just trying to use the JSON response directly (which is a string, just like anything else you receive over the wire)? You need to show the *actual code* that is *actually running* on the Pi, *and* also show *exactly* how you are providing the data.

Answer (score 0):

`body["definitions"]` is returning a string, say "hello", so if you write:

```
body["definitions"]["0"]
```

that is equivalent to:

```
"hello"["0"]
```

which produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

But if you write:

```
"hello"[0]
```

you get:

```
'h'
```